# Why would I need Docker for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am relatively new to Docker. And it's pretty amazing.

Well, I understand that for language like PHP. I think it does really make sense to use Docker, because of the PHP environment.

But why would i need to use docker for Node.js while i can simply 'npm install' and 'npm start' and I am all done.

I believe I have missed something here I think. What did I miss?

Comment: In PHP you can do `composer install` and `php -S localhost:8080` and you're all done. Docker is still useful since it permits you to carefully control your whole OS build. Any web app can be susceptible to OS-level configuration changes.

Comment: on top of what @halfer has already said, there are also security implications, since your app is "contained" there's a certain level of barrier for each container (this is highly dependent on specific app configuration and how much access the container has to the host though). The highest benefit by far though, is that you have the assurance that no matter where your app is deployed it will run the same way. this is docker's primary purpose. regardless of os or package install.

Comment: Waw, i didn't know that @halfer. I thought i have to configure lamp-sever on my machine and then put my code inside /var/www/html to get php works.

Comment: @Nalaurien, Hmm. I still can't see the benefits. Isn't nodejs app always work without needing any external configuration?  Is there any case where nodejs app doesn't work, needs certain environment, or it should be "contained" ? I have never deploy nodejs into production. Maybe there's certain steps beside npm install and npm start in deploying nodejs to production that could be handled easily by docker?

Answer (score 0):

The main point worth noting is that all applications depend on a machine build. Trivial apps (in Node or PHP or anything) can just be started on the console, but they still need a server and a package manager.

The list then might comprise of any of the following:

- The base server is chosen for a balance of speed, image size, security approach or update cautiousness (Ubuntu for features, CentOS for caution, Alpine for image size, etc)
- Run-time software such as PHP, Apache, NginX, Node, etc.
- server write permissions set up on an internal cache folder
- the installation of a specific version of cURL
- a local cache or queue installation (Redis, Memcache, etc)
- a specific PHP extension installed, such as a database extension (or system equivalent in another language)
- User accounts
- Package management software like Composer and NPM
- Your app, fetched from version control or a build server
- An installation of your packages for your app
- Install fonts
- Set timezone and localisations

Here is a Dockerfile I wrote recently (for a relatively simple set of functional tests):

```
# Docker build script for the Command Agent system

FROM ubuntu

# Do a system update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y

# Basic dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y git openssl

# Install PHP
# Composer needs openssl, json, phar, iconv/mbstring
# Composer recommends zlib
# PHPUnit needs dom, mbstring
RUN apt-get install -y php php-json php-phar php-mbstring php-dom php-zip
# @todo What names are php-ssl and php-zlib under?

# Install SSH server
# Expect is to handle tty automation
# Netcat is required to send messages
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server expect netcat

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" nonpriv
# It looks like passwordless access does not work unless the user has a password!
RUN echo 'nonpriv:Password123' | chpasswd

# We need to be able to ask for a root password (so lets give it one)
RUN echo 'root:Password123' | chpasswd

# Copy over installation scripts
COPY install /tmp/install
RUN chmod u+rx /tmp/install/_*.sh && \
    chown -R nonpriv:nonpriv /tmp/install

# Install Composer
# See https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-composer-programmatically.md
RUN cd /tmp && sh /tmp/install/composer.sh

# Copy dependendencies
COPY composer.json /root/command-agent/composer.json
COPY composer.lock /root/command-agent/composer.lock

# Install deps using Composer (include dev deps)
# @todo Don't run composer as root, https://getcomposer.org/root
RUN cd /root/command-agent && php /tmp/composer.phar install

# Apply patch to PHPUnit. This is a bit hacky, but the only way I can see to
# fully turn off output buffering. Unfortunately these methods are private,
# so standard approaches to removing them (an override method) would not work.
# The only other alternative is using runkit, and I think that might be +more+
# hacky :)
COPY patch /root/command-agent/patch
RUN patch -p1 \
    /root/command-agent/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php \
    /root/command-agent/patch/disable_ob.patch

# Copy code
COPY bin /root/command-agent/bin
COPY src /root/command-agent/src
COPY test /root/command-agent/test
COPY entry-point.sh /root/command-agent/entry-point.sh
COPY expect.sh /root/command-agent/expect.sh
COPY phpunit.xml /root/command-agent/phpunit.xml
RUN ln -s /root/command-agent/vendor/bin/phpunit /root/command-agent/phpunit

# Allow non-priv user to read/exec root files
RUN chown -R root:nonpriv /root && \
    chmod -R g-w /root && \
    chmod -R g+rx /root

# This should be privileged access only
COPY test/functional/assets/agent_auth /root/.agent_auth
COPY test/functional/assets/agent_auth_wrong /root/.agent_auth_wrong
COPY test/functional/assets/bad_perms_agent_auth /root/.bad_perms_agent_auth
RUN chmod 400 /root/.agent_auth*

# Run tests
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/root/command-agent/entry-point.sh"]
```

That is quite lengthy, and is certainly something I do not want to repeat every time I make a fresh deployment.